# My inbox and recent achievements keep reincarnating

Tags: bug, notification-bar

Every time I renew my page, I get a green and red notification at the top of the page, for notifications that I have already seen.

As more notifications appear, the reincarnating number has gone up.  It started when I logged on an hour ago, with the one new message and one rep change.

It goes away after I acknowledge it while I am on the page, but reappears as soon as I navigate to a new page.

Comment: Both inbox and achievement indicators have severe issues after the failover tests late yesterday.

Comment: Another report (with screenshots) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238158/162102

Comment: It just got worse - now my inbox isn't even registering new messages.