# Top-bar notifications are not updating (a) after I view them and (b) to reflect new changes

Tags: support, notifications

This is new behavior tonight: both the reputation and inbox counters are stuck in time.

My reputation notification indicator seems to be stuck at a particular value; it shows "+52" regardless of what I do.  In the following screen shot you can see that these notifications are not new (they were an hour ago, but I've opened that notification thingy several times now):

[image: screen shot]

After I click on the notification it goes away on the current page -- but on the next page-load it's back, on multiple sites.  The same thing happens with the inbox notification; after I clicked that and went to a new page the red 4 was back.

This happens in Firefox (31.0) and Chrome (36.0.1985.125) on Mac OS 10.6, and I'm also seeing it in Chrome on my Android phone.

Further, while investigating this and writing this post, I got two new rep updates -- and they neither changed the count nor show up in the drop-down:

[image: new invisible rep]

(I took the first screen shot after these events occurred.)

I think I've seen reports of the first problem -- the notice not dismissing -- before, but can't find them.  I can't remember seeing reports of the second problem.

Comment: It's all gone haywire after the switch to Oregon and back (see https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/94861337469/read-write-oregon-data-center-test-august-16th-2014).

Comment: It will, to be replaced by other half-hearted values. Only *some* reputation change events make it through, to then be stuck for a while.